# Arrastrar un div hmtl no funciona en vista móvil del devtools

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy implementado este [ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_draggable) para poder arrastrar un `div` por la pantalla. Todo me funciona bien , pero cuando uso el modo `mobile` de las `devTools` de `Chrome` no puedo mover el `div` en cuya cabecera pone

```
click here to move
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal y como lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 0):

Este error se verá también en el navegador movile, ya que tambien está emulando sus limitantes.

Para permitir que el usuario arrastre un div en un dispositivo móvil usando JavaScript y HTML5, debes asegurarte de que estás utilizando la API de arrastrar y soltar de HTML5. Esto se logra a través del uso de los eventos [dragstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragstart_event), [drag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent), y [dragend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragend_event) en el elemento que deseas arrastrar, así como el uso de la propiedad [draggable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable) en el elemento para indicar que puede ser arrastrado.

Comment: tienes por ahí algún ejemplo en ćodigo?

Comment: Aquí hay uno pero tampoco funciona 
https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/qEJaQq